# Can't Install Ubuntu 16.04 on Toshiba Satellite c600 laptop

Tags: system-installation

When I try install Ubuntu 16.04 on my old laptop( it has windows xp) it shutdown without error messages. Why it happenens?
Laptop charackteristic:
Intel® Pentium® processor P6200 2.13 GHz
2,048 (1x) MB, DDR3 RAM (1,066 MHz)
Intel® Graphics Media Accelerator HD
Hard disk 320 GB

I'm use 32-bit PC (i386) desktop image Ubuntu 16.04. I did usb flash with Startup Disk Creator.

Comment: It may be overheating.

Comment: @Pilot6 is right. "Wihout error messages" means that it's a hardware-caused shutdown, not Ubuntu. Check your power supply and heat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a hardware issue, most likely. I would make sure the memory is correctly slotted. Try removing it and putting it back in-place just to be suer. If the laptop does this behaviour when you don't try to boot of a live USB or CD, then then next logical culprit in that the CPU is reaching the maximum heat threshold and aborting boot (safety feature).

Try the following:

- Clean the computer. Make sure the CUP Cooling is taking air good and that it's not full of dust.
- Try to boot only into the BIOS. This will let you run a memory test, which you can probably get away without doing. But more importantly you should comb thought the settings and turn off anything like secure boot.

  - Also it can't hurt to make edit your boot order so that the computer tries to boot from the CD or USB first before the hard-drive. This just makes think a little easer for you when you go to install Ubuntu. This will be good to check so that you can see if there are any weird boot options enabled as first priority. While normally you can get away with non ideal boot sequence, since your having problem it's best to have all your bases covered.
- Finally, you might just have a bad computer. If you try all above and your still having the same problem then you may want to take the computer to a technician that can accentually replace components soldered to the motherboard. But at that point, given the cost of the work and that it's an older computer this might be the end of it's life.

Since the computer is older, and you didn't say that is wasn't abnormal behaviour for it, it sounds like you haven't been using this machine too much lately. Because you haven't used this computer in while and it's not getting far into the boot, I'm willing to bet it's the CPU overhearing and shutting down as a safety feature.

Comment: Yes it was one of ram slot(i has two - 2Gb and 4Gb). I pushed off 4Gb and Ubuntu have run.

Comment: Great. Happy it worked out for you.